# ng-repeat not updating after it's model changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two controllers, one for my form, and one for showing docs.
So, I wanted to update records list after user submits the form, because of that I created a service and shared a variable between two controllers:

```
accountingApp.factory('sharedProperties', function () {
   var shareableData = []

   return {
      getProperty: function (property) {
         return shareableData[property];
      },
      setProperty: function(property, value) {
         shareableData[property] = value;
      }
   };
});
```

To get docs, I'm setting accDocs that lives in service, and then getting it to attach to vm.accDocs and later on html, using it like `ng-repeat="accDoc in vm.accDocs"`

```
function accDocsController(api, sharedProperties) {
  var vm = this;

  sharedProperties.setProperty("accDocs", api.getAccDocs(vm));
  vm.accDocs = sharedProperties.getProperty("accDocs");
}
```

In the form's contorller, this is what's happening:

```
vm.submit = function(vm) {
     if (vm.entryForms.$valid) {
        api.newAccDoc(...);

        console.log(sharedProperties.getProperty("accDocs")); // returns the actual array
        sharedProperties.setProperty("accDocs", null);
        console.log(sharedProperties.getProperty("accDocs")); // returns null
     }
  };
```

After submitting the form, docs wont gone. I can log `vm.accDocs` with ng-inspector and see its still full of objects.

Where is my problem?

Comment: Can you create a snippet with a complete sample (including the view as well)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are replacing the value. So `vm.accDocs` is bound to the original value, while the factory now contains the new value. You can fix this easily by wrapping your factory state data in a parent object and binding to that. For example:

```
accountingApp.factory('sharedProperties', function () {
    var state = {
        shareableData: []
    };

    return {
        getState: function(){
            return state;
        },
        setProperty: function(property, value) {
            state.shareableData[property] = value;
        }
    };
});
```

Then instead of binding directly to the value you want, you bind to the state itself, and reference the desired value with a `.`. For example:

```
vm.accDocsState = sharedProperties.getState();
```

and in the HTML (might be incorrect because I can't see your code, but hopefully you get the idea):

```
ng-repeat="accDoc in vm.accDocsState.accDocs"
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your **accDocsController** at the **sharedProperties.setProperty()** function.

```
// api.getAccDocs(vm) is undefined at this moment
sharedProperties.setProperty("accDocs", api.getAccDocs(vm));
```

You're using a service **api.getAccDocs(vm)** which fetches data with an http request. (Correct me if I'm wrong).

You should return a promise from this service, so you can pass the data when it actually exists.

## Solution:

Inject [Angular's $q service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) in your **api-service**.

#### Service (api)

Your service should look something like this:

```
var API = {};

function getAccDocs(vm) {

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.get("http://yourapi.com")
        .then(function onGotAccDocs(response) {
            // response = [{...}, {...}]
            deferred.resolve(response);
        }, function onGetAccDocsFailed(error) {
            deffered.reject(error);
        });

    return deferred.promise;
}

API.getAccDocs = getAccDocs;
```

**Controller (accDocsController)**
Please slightly modify your controller into this:

```
function accDocsController(api, sharedProperties) {

    var vm = this;

    function initialize() {

        api.getAccDocs(vm)
            .then(function onGotAccDocs(response) {
                console.info('AccDocs retrieved succesfully!', response);

                // Now we can set sharedProperties 'accDocs' since we've got data!
                sharedProperties.setProperty("accDocs", response);
                vm.accDocs = sharedProperties.getProperty("accDocs");

            }, function onGetAccDocsFailed(error) {
                console.error('Could not retrieve accDocs', error);
            });

    }


    // --- Initialize ---
    initialize();

}
```

Comment: This is not a good way to use $http, as it already returns a promise so your deferred is redundant. The error will also still occur due to the scope problem.

Answer (score 0):

If on term "submit" you meaning to post your form to server and then return innitial view, then you page reloads and if your both controllers located on same page they are recreated too and accDocs are initialized at accDocsController constructor.